# Maven - Calling a module from Parent POM based on the profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml, profiles

I have a module which is supposed to produce two artifacts (war's). The only difference between the two WAR's is the web.xml being used.
I did this with the help of Maven Profiles...

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>com</artifactId>
    <groupId>myProj</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>myProj.module1</groupId>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>module1</id>
        <build>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>module1</warName>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web_module1.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>


    <profile>
        <id>module2</id>
        <build>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>module2</warName>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web_module2.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Q1: How can I call this POM from super POM so that both the Profiles are activated?

Q2: Is it possible to install both the generated artifacts in Local repository?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to [activate several profiles at the same time](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), you simply have to run `mvn ... -Pprofile1,profile2` command.

However, in your case, this is against one main Maven convention, which states that `one project = one artifact`. This means that you can't create 2 WAR at the same time. If you activate both profiles, one configuration of the `maven-war-plugin` will be overriden by the second profile, and then, you will finally get 1 WAR, with one web.xml.

If you want to get 2 WARs, the solution are to use [WAR overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) (i.e. the second war is another project that depends on war #1), or run two separate Maven commands, one per profile.

Comment: Thanks romaintaz.  Is there any way by which I can call my child pom with the help of a profile... something that can be done to:  `<module>....</module>`

Comment: Well, I used "Overlays". The two of the artifacts were using the same codebase, but different "web.xml"